# What I am doing wrong with Obj-c delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a new tabbed view project in Xcode in firstViewController I created a protocol like this

```
@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)myProtocolMethodOne;
@end


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak) id<myProtocol> mypDelegate;

- (IBAction)button1Tap:(id)sender;

@end
```

In .m file I did this

```
@synthesize mypDelegate;
.
.
.
- (IBAction)button1Tap:(id)sender
{
    [mypDelegate myProtocolMethodOne];
}
```

This is secondViewController .h file

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <myProtocol>

@property (strong) FirstViewController *fvc;

@end
```

This is .m file

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Second", @"Second");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
        _fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
        [_fvc setMypDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)myProtocolMethodOne
{
    NSLog(@"2nd VC");
    [[self tabBarItem]setBadgeValue:@"ok"];
}
```

myProtocolMethodOne is not working, what I did wrong?

Comment: How is FirstViewController getting on screen so you can tap its button1Tap button? You alloc init an instance, but I don't see any code to get its view on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
[_fvc setMypDelegate:self];
```

You're setting the delegate to a completely new `FirstViewController`, but not the one who trigger your method `- (IBAction)button1Tap:(id)sender`

You have to pass your delegate when you're doing the transition between your 2 view controllers, for example in `- prepareForSegue:` or when you doing `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]`

Comment: I have only one FirstViewController, how it can be completely new one.

Comment: It's a new on since your doing `[[FirstViewController alloc]init]`. Are you dealing with Storyboard or XIB ?

Comment: No storyboards but firstVC has xib file

Comment: even after alloc & init it will contain the properties, please can you explain in detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is Best site with source code for learn basic about protocol.](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

////// .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

@required

-(void)myProtocolMethodOne;

@end

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    id <myProtocol> mypDelegate;
}

@property (retain) id mypDelegate;

- (IBAction)button1Tap:(id)sender;

@end
```

/////////  .m file

```
@synthesize mypDelegate;
.
.
.
.
- (void)processComplete
{
    [[self mypDelegate] myProtocolMethodOne];
}
```